# realtive width sub-menu 100% width of header

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a header width sub-menu. I would like to align the sub-menu with its parent menu-item, but the background to be 100% of width of the header.

Since the menu is positioned realative to its parent element the width of the sub menu to 100% of the header has been difficult to achieve.

```css
.menu-main .menu .menu-item {
    position: relative;
}

.menu > li > ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    top: 150px;
    padding: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease .15s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease .15s;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease .15s;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease .15s;
    transition: all .3s ease .15s;
}
```

```html
   <li class="menu-item withchildren">
         <a class="menu-link" href="/brandid">Brändid</a>
              <!-- this should be full width with white background -->
              <ul class="submenu">
                   <li class="menu-item">
                    <a class="menu-link" href="/brandid/rolf-benz">Rolf-Benz</a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
              <!-- end submenu -->
    </li>
```

JSFiddle of situation: https://jsfiddle.net/wo66damx/2/

Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

```
    .menu {
position: relative;
display:inline-block;
width:100%; }
```

You can set the .menu class to width: 100%; This worked for me.
Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wo66damx/11/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's supposed to work with other menu items combined: https://jsfiddle.net/wo66damx/12/

Answer (score 0):

Since you have javascript tag...

```
links=document.querySelectorAll('.menu-link');
for(i=0;i<links.length;i++) {
links[i].onmouseover = function() {

sub=this.parentNode.querySelector('.submenu');

if(sub!==null) {
//if should be aligned with header
sub.style.left=document.querySelector('.header').offsetLeft+'px';
//if should be aligned with link
//sub.style.left=this.offsetLeft+'px';
sub.style.width=document.querySelector('.header').offsetWidth+'px';
}
}

}
```

DEMO:

```js
links=document.querySelectorAll('.menu-link');
for(i=0;i<links.length;i++) {
links[i].onmouseover = function() {

sub=this.parentNode.querySelector('.submenu');
//if should be aligned with header
if(sub!==null) {
sub.style.left=document.querySelector('.header').offsetLeft+'px';
//if should be aligned with link
//sub.style.left=this.offsetLeft+'px';
sub.style.width=document.querySelector('.header').offsetWidth+'px';
}
}

}
```

```css
body {
  background:black;
  }

.header {
  width:500px;
  background:#fff;
}
.menu {
    
    display:inline-block;
  
}

li:hover > ul {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    overflow: visible;
}
li > ul {
  list-style-type:none;

    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%; /* how can I get this 100% of header ? */
    top: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease .15s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease .15s;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease .15s;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease .15s;
    transition: all .3s ease .15s;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
<li class="menu withchildren">
      <a class="menu-link" href="/brandid">Brändid</a>
          <!-- this should be full width with white background -->
          <ul class="submenu">
               <li class="menu-item">
                <a class="menu-link" href="/brandid/rolf-benz">Rolf-Benz</a>
              </li>
              <li class="menu-item">
                <a class="menu-link" href="/brandid/rolf-benz">Rolf-Benz</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
          <!-- end submenu -->
</li>
<li class="menu withchildren">
      <a class="menu-link" href="/brandid">Brändid</a>
          <!-- this should be full width with white background -->
          <ul class="submenu">
               <li class="menu-item">
                <a class="menu-link" href="/brandid/rolf-benz">Rolf-Benz22222222</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
          <!-- end submenu -->
</li>
</div>
```

Also, you will have to remove position:relative from .menu-link, so .submenu position can be calculated relative to the body... Probably pure CSS solution is possible, too (but with some HTML re-structuring).

Answer (score 0):

You can also build menu and submenu seperate. Gives you options to fancy things up. And gives you flexibel build options towards mobile.
This is q very basic model.

```
<header>
  <!-- head nav -->
  <ul class="menu">
   <li><a href="#" id="click1" class="item1">Link 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" id="click2" class="item2">Link 2</a></li>
</ul>
<!-- sub nav dropdowns -->
<div id="link1" class="drop1 pos">
 <ul class="submenu">
   <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Sub 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Sub 2</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
<div id="link2" class="drop2 pos">
 <ul class="submenu">
   <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Sub 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Sub 2</a></li>
 </ul>
```

[js dropdown jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wimvandurme/L587f0vp/)